# SwiftUI How do I capture a keyboard shortcut with a button

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, macos-catalina

I am writing a menubar application with a popup view but no menu and no storyboard. Among other things, I want to activate a button with keyboard shortcut.

Everything I have found so far is either for Swift 2.0 or for menu based applications. I would like my application to run on Catalina, though by the time it is finished I know that Big Sur will be out.

Is there a way for a SwiftUI button to respond to a keyboard shortcut, or some other way for a view to do that?

I am on MacOS 10.15.6, and XCode 11.7.

Comment: What if your application is not currently at front?

Comment: @ElTomato Then the popover loses focus and disappears.

Comment: You aren't telling the whole story, but you can assign a keyboard shortcut to a button (`NSButton`).